# In meteorjs, where should I declare a function, so calls to it work from anywhere?

Tags: meteor

And if this function needs other libraries declared before it?
(such as bootstrap, less, paperjs)

In other words, how can I control the import order?

Answer (score 2):

Packages always load first, so you can simply define them inside `/lib/*`.

[Check the docs for more info](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Comment: So, it means we need to make a package of our functions. If there is no mean to chose the order packages are loaded, it means we would need to declare dependent things in the same file. (in my beginners's knowledge).

Comment: No, there are very clear rules described in the docs i linked. If you have libs that you depend on in your `/lib` directory, you could simply put them in `/lib/lib`. I'd put the things you listed in `/client/compatibility` tough. This gets executed before other client-side files.

Answer (score 0):

If the function needs access to the DOM, put it in `client/lib`

else, put it in `/lib`

[DOCS](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp)